# The loop iterate accurately according to length, but same record insert in each iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets, for-loop

I am using [Datatables.net](http://datatables.net/) with Java servlet:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dayClosing').click(function () {
        $.post("RecallHoldTrx", {
            TrxHoldID: oData[0]
        }, function (data2) {
            for (k = 0; k < data2.length; k++) {
                var getItemCode = data2[k];
                $.post("GetItemDetail", {
                    itemCode: getItemCode
                }, function (data) {
                    oTable.fnAddData([data[0], data[1]]);
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The loop iterate accurately according it the length, but the same record insert in each iteration;but

When I put `alert()` after the `var getItemCode = data2[k];` as

```
var getItemCode = data2[k];
alert(getItemCode);
```

As I press Ok, OK, each iteration insert new row in datatables,accurately.But as I remove the alert, same record insert in each iteration, it is sometime first record or sometime last record.

How we can insert row with new data, without alert?

NOTE:[oTable.fnAddData()](http://datatables.net/api) is used to add row in [Datatables.net](http://datatables.net/)

Comment: Hiya, can you please try and jsfiddle this, I might be able to help you out, `:)`

Comment: Instead of `alert`, try `console.log(getItemCode)`. Also before the call to `oTable.fnAddData`, add `console.log(data[0]); console.log(data[1]);` That way you will see a trace of what you were doing in your browser's debug console but it will still run at full speed. (Most likely when you use alert this creates a delay that hides the problem.)

Comment: @DanielEarwicker is it possible to that loop go for second iteration without performing all the task in the loop, even database communication? I am using Jquery.

Comment: Yes. Each iteration of the loop says `$.post("GetItemDetail", ...` which only *starts* a transaction with the server. It doesn't wait for it to finish. But that in itself shouldn't be a problem for your code, because you only depend on `data` which is the response from the server. By putting in your own logging you can see if the problem is in your code or elsewhere (in `fnAddData` or the server)

Comment: Yes. @DanielEarwicker you are right that It doesn't wait for it to finish. What is resolution or alternative solution in your point of view?

Comment: Did you add the calls to `console.log` yet?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i would recommend sending all data in the first ajax-reponse. Why should you make so many ajax-calls if it could be done by one?

I think you have a problem with scoping. You could use $.each for looping over your resultset. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dayClosing').click(function () {
        $.post("RecallHoldTrx", {
            TrxHoldID: oData[0]
        }, function (data2) {
            $.each(data2,function(index,item) {
                $.post("GetItemDetail", {
                    itemCode: item
                }, function (data) {
                    oTable.fnAddData([data[0], data[1]]);
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```